# Push certificates revoke

Tags: ios, app-store, push-notification

I have an app on Appstore, enabled for push notifications. 
I revoked and renewed the push distribution certificate for that app and I did NOT resubmitted the app.
Now might I have problems on sending push messages to the installed apps (with the new certificate)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't do - the certificate isn't actually referenced anywhere in the app itself.

Comment: i'm not sure about this, the aps token may be related to this certificate?